# How to set and run Lucene correctly java-android

Tags: java, android, html, apache, lucene

I made an asset folder that contians a large number of html files(+8000) that I want to search inside using Lucene .
So I imported jar file ,      and wrote some code  :
`Indexer`:

```
public class Indexer {

private IndexWriter writer;

public Indexer(String indexDirectoryPath) throws IOException{
    //this directory will contain the indexes
    Directory indexDirectory =
            FSDirectory.open(new File(indexDirectoryPath));

    //create the indexer
    writer = new IndexWriter(indexDirectory,
            new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_36),true,
            IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED);
}

public void close() throws CorruptIndexException, IOException{
    writer.close();
}

private Document getDocument(File file) throws IOException{
    Document document = new Document();

    //index file contents
    Field contentField = new Field(LuceneConstants.CONTENTS,
            new FileReader(file));
    //index file name
    Field fileNameField = new Field(LuceneConstants.FILE_NAME,
            file.getName(),
            Field.Store.YES,Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED);
    //index file path
    Field filePathField = new Field(LuceneConstants.FILE_PATH,
            file.getCanonicalPath(),
            Field.Store.YES,Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED);

    document.add(contentField);
    document.add(fileNameField);
    document.add(filePathField);

    return document;
}

private void indexFile(File file) throws IOException{
    System.out.println("Indexing "+file.getCanonicalPath());
    Document document = getDocument(file);
    writer.addDocument(document);
}

public int createIndex(String dataDirPath, FileFilter filter)
        throws IOException{
    //get all files in the data directory
    File[] files = new File(dataDirPath).listFiles();

    for (File file : files) {
        if(!file.isDirectory()
                && !file.isHidden()
                && file.exists()
                && file.canRead()
                && filter.accept(file)
                ){
            indexFile(file);
        }
    }
    return writer.numDocs();
}}
```

`LuceneConstants`:

```
public class LuceneConstants {
public static final String CONTENTS="contents";
public static final String FILE_NAME="filename";
public static final String FILE_PATH="filepath";
public static final int MAX_SEARCH = 10;}
```

`Searcher`:

```
public class Searcher {
IndexSearcher indexSearcher;
QueryParser queryParser;
Query query;

public Searcher(String indexDirectoryPath)
        throws IOException{
    Directory indexDirectory =
            FSDirectory.open(new File(indexDirectoryPath));
    indexSearcher = new IndexSearcher(indexDirectory);
    queryParser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_36,
            LuceneConstants.CONTENTS,
            new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_36));
}

public TopDocs search( String searchQuery)
        throws IOException, ParseException{
    query = queryParser.parse(searchQuery);
    return indexSearcher.search(query, LuceneConstants.MAX_SEARCH);
}

public Document getDocument(ScoreDoc scoreDoc)
        throws CorruptIndexException, IOException{
    return indexSearcher.doc(scoreDoc.doc);
}

public void close() throws IOException{
    indexSearcher.close();
}}
```

`TextFileFilter`:

```
public class TextFileFilter implements FileFilter {
@Override
public boolean accept(File pathname) {
    return pathname.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".html");
}}
```

and in `MySearch` class :

```
        // Declare Variables
String indexDir = "/storage/sdcard0";
String dataDir = "file:///android_asset/";
Indexer indexer;
Searcher searcher;
```

filter method inside MySearch class

```
        public void filter(String charText) throws FileNotFoundException {    
         if (charText.length() >= 3) {
            MySearch tester;
            try {
                tester = new MySearch ();
                tester.createIndex();
                tester.search(charText);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

**`createIndex()`:**

```
 private void createIndex() throws IOException{
    indexer = new Indexer(indexDir);
    int numIndexed;
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    numIndexed = indexer.createIndex(dataDir, new TextFileFilter());
    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    indexer.close();

}
```

**`search()`  :**

```
private void search(String searchQuery) throws IOException, ParseException{
    searcher = new Searcher(indexDir);
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    TopDocs hits = searcher.search(searchQuery);
    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    for(ScoreDoc scoreDoc : hits.scoreDocs) {
        Document doc = searcher.getDocument(scoreDoc);
                Log.d("path", doc.get(LuceneConstants.FILE_PATH));
    }
    searcher.close();
}
```

**Error messages:**

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.javier.MaterialDesignApp.lucene.Indexer.createIndex(Indexer.java:69)
 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.javier.MaterialDesignApp.medic_list.MySearch .createIndex(MySearch .java:479)//this line :        numIndexed = indexer.createIndex(dataDir, new TextFileFilter());
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.javier.MaterialDesignApp.medic_list.MySearch .filter(MySearch .java:183) //this line                     tester.createIndex();
```

**Question:**
1-How can i set and run lucene correctly to search inside this large number of files ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Lucene knows nothing about Android, and it will not be able to use `file:///android_asset` values. Also, please do not waste the user's time building the index on their device. If the data is packaged in assets, the data will not be changing for the life of this version of the app. Build the index on your development machine and include it, along with the 8000 files, in assets. Then, you only need to worry about searching in Android code, not indexing. I take this approach with the APK edition of [my book](https://commonsware.com/Android), though I use SQLite and FTS3 instead of Lucene.

Comment: @CommonsWare I once tried to build my index on my machine. When I searched through the index on my android device. I got no result. Just because the file formats are different. So I am guessing that lucene is platform dependent.

Comment: I find that somewhat difficult to believe, as I am not aware that Lucene has platform-specific code. Regardless, that is still no excuse for wasting your users' time and devices building full-text search indexes on their devices for static data. Use something else (e.g., SQLite FTS3), figure out why Lucene is not behaving for you, switch to searching via a Web service, etc.